# How to return xls excel file response using REST API controller in weburl

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I need to return x ls excel file in response using Rest API controller in web URL in spring i am not getting data from Database just setting fix value now i have written controller part and service manager part but i am finding the following errors:

in console :

> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

and in browser:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.

code for controller :

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/excel")
 public class ExcelController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ExcelManager` is not declared as a bean.
You need either add `@Service` above your ExcelManager class definition, or declare it in `applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your service class with the annotation `@Service`
. Otherwise Spring will not be able to autowire it.

Comment: after adding@service in manager  it gives error----Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'excelManagerImpl';

Comment: In your config file, be sure that the configuration of component-scan include the package where is your service.